# How can I insert vertical blank space into an HTML document?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I am writing a quiz in HTML and I would like to insert a consistent blank vertical space between questions (like one would use `vspace{3 cm}` in [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)).

For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
     This is the first question?
      <!-- This is where I want about 3 cm of space -->
    </p>
    <p>
     This is the second question?
     <!-- This is where I want about 3 cm of space -->
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a straightforward way of doing this using just HTML and CSS?

How can I insert vertical blank space into an HTML document?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Read up some on CSS. It's fun: *[CSS: em, px, pt, cm, in…](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)*

```
<style>
  .bottom-three {
     margin-bottom: 3cm;
  }
</style>


<p class="bottom-three">
   This is the first question?
</p>
<p class="bottom-three">
   This is the second question?
</p>
```

Comment: thanks, that was the clue I needed - I actually created a class for quiz questions and then put each question inside <div>.  works great.

Answer (score 29):

While the previous answers are probably best for this situation, if you just want to do a one-off and don't want to bother with modifying other files, you can in-line the CSS.

```
<p style="margin-bottom:3cm;">This is the first question?</p>
```

Answer (score 20):

I always use this cheap word for vertical spaces.

```
    <p>Q1</p>
    <br>
    <p>Q2</p>
```

Comment: simple and quick

Comment: What do you mean by *"cheap word"*? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 12):

Write it like this:

```css
p {
    padding-bottom: 3cm;
}
```

Or

```css
p {
    margin-bottom: 3cm;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot.  I am still learning to think "html" as I switch away from LaTeX.

Comment: Off topic, but I'm curious why you seem to feel HTML is better for this purpose than LaTeX?

Comment: @scala_is_awesome I know this comment is very very old but I just happened upon it so in case you are still curious...  I use LaTeX a lot for my class materials but I have started using html more and more for things that do not need the high polish of LaTeX and will go up on my class webpage.  They are a bit easier to edit on the fly and are easier to share in an editable format for Word-only users, since Word can parse html.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**; Use `text`, which must be an array of strings of length of `x`. Insert `{text}` in `hovertemplate`.

https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/ has next MWE.

Understand how

```
text = ['Custom text {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(5)]
```

makes it of length of `x`. If always same text, then use: `text=["foo"] * 5`.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = [1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [2.02825,1.63728,6.83839,4.8485,4.73463],
    hovertemplate =
    '<i>Price</i>: $%{y:.2f}'+
    '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>'+
    '<b>%{text}</b>',
    text = ['Custom text {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(5)],
    showlegend = False))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x = [1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [3.02825,2.63728,4.83839,3.8485,1.73463],
    hovertemplate = 'Price: %{y:$.2f}<extra></extra>',
    showlegend = False))

fig.update_layout(
    hoverlabel_align = 'right',
    title = "Set hover text with hovertemplate")

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple little DRY function.

```
function html_gap(some_size) {return '<br><span style="font-size: ' + some_size + '; vertical-align: text-bottom;"></span>'}
```

Replace `'<br>'` with eg `html_gap("3ch")` in any text. Uses any valid CSS size. This will not produce gaps smaller than the standard container line break.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61k9cy5j/3/)